# html table line cannot be insert to the second layout

Tags: html, css

May i know is there any ways to insert the table layout from the first layout into the second layout using html? the layout is using an a4 page format size. I created two layout as be mention above. Now i'm stuck while to have a table layout in second page/layout, which is basically inherited table property from the first table. Please see the picture that be attached for your kind reference. I'm not attaching the code as I not sure is the right code.[two layout/table picture- please click this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eAQm.png)

```html
<html>
<head>
   <title>Quotation</title>
   <style type="text/css">

   body{
      background: white;
   }
  
      .mypg {width: 660px; height: 1122px;
         margin: 2px auto 2px auto;
         background: white;
         border-style:solid black;
         box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
         padding: 90px;}

page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
page[size="A4"] {  
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm; 
}


 img {
  float: left; 
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  position: center;




}
/*this is for company name    */
 comname{
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 11%;
  padding-top: 280%;
  font-size: 100%;


 }
/*company address    */
 address{
  position: top;
  padding-left: 40%;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-family: "Arial";
 
} 

/*company registration number */
h{
   position: center;
  top: 50px;
  padding-left: 2px;;
  padding-right: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-size: 10%;
}

/*document name -quotation */
 h2{
  position: center;
  top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-size: 120%;
  padding-left:6%;


  
}
/*paragraph element that be can override */
.p{
  position: center;  
  left: 80px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right:60px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 0;
  line-height: 10px;
  margin:0;

  
}
/*company email tag */
.p3{
  text-decoration: underline;

}
/*                  */     
.floatright {
    float: right;
    background-color: white;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30%;
    padding-left: 20%;
}

.floatleft {
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30%;
    padding-left: 8%;

}

.three   {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: white;
    height: 600px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 1000px;
}



th { 
  width:100px
  font-weight: normal;
  
}

td {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}


tr {
  
  page-break-after:auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

div.chapter, div.appendix {
    page-break-after: always;
}


/* th {
    border-right:solid black;
    border-bottom:solid black;
    border-left:solid black;
    border-top:solid black;
}*/

.none{ 
border-style: none;

}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-style: solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
     page-break-inside:auto
    


}


dt { 
display:block; 
font-size:80%;
}

dt {
content:':';

}

dd { 
display:block;
font-size:80%;
}

section {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1.5%;
  width: 30%;
}

head{
  display:table-header-group;
}

p.tfoot{
 /* display:table-footer-group; */ 
  line-height:300%;
  padding-left:8%;
  font-size:80%;
}

.terms{
font-size:80%;
}

space{
  width:20px;
  padding-right:15px;
  padding-left:35px;

}

p.lineheader1{
  padding-left: 8%;
  padding-top:15%;
  font-size:80%;
  height:20%;
  
}

p.lineheader2{
  padding-left: 8%;
  padding-top:15%;
  font-size:80%;
  height:20%;
  
}

styleline{
  padding-left:8%;
   padding-top: 15%;
}

table2{
  padding-top:40%;
  margin-top:20%;
  line-height:60%;

}


.floatleft2{
  padding-top:180%;
  margin-top:100%;
      float: left;
    background-color: white;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30%;
    padding-left: 8%;
    position:fixed;

}

hr{
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: black;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding-left:15px;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    left: 65px;
    padding-top:324px;
  
}

hr2{
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: solid black;
    margin-top:-40px;
    padding-right:15px;
    width:30%;
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    right: 30px;



}

.floatright2{
  float:right;
      line-height:1px;
  

}

hr.floatright2{
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: solid black;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding-left:15px;
    width:30%;
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    left: 55px;
    padding-top:5%;
      height: 300;

}

space2{
  width:40px;
  padding-right:8px;
  padding-left:49%;
  

}

spacedate{
  width:900%;
  padding-left:330%;
  padding-right:8%;
  
  

}

date{
  float:right;
  padding-left:85%;
  padding-right:33%;
  line-height:-80px;
  font-size:80%;

}

mdname{
  float:left;
  padding-right:85%;
  padding-left:8%;
  font-size:80%;
}

p.ufoot{
  font-size:50%;
  padding-left:8%;
  line-height:400%;

}

spacesign{
  width:50%;
  padding-left:30%;
  padding-right:4%;
  

}

.table-bordered{
  
}

hrline{
 display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: white;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding-left:15px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    left: 65px;
    padding-top:2024px;


}

th { 
  width:100px
  font-weight: normal;
  
}

td {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}


ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

div.chapter, div.appendix {
    page-break-after: always;
}


 th {
    border-right:solid black;
    border-bottom:solid black;
    border-left:solid black;
    border-top:solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-style: solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    
}


   
</style>
 
 

   <div class="mypg">
   <!--     <div class="header"> -->
        <img class="img"; src="\Users\User\Desktop\Excersice Html\promosys_logo1.jpg" alt="promosys_logo">
    <div>
        <comname>PROMOSYS(M) TECHNOLOGY (M) SDN. BHD.</comname><h>(650109-T)</h><br>
        <address>No. 27, Jalan Rebena 3, Off Jalan Seruling 59, Taman Klang Jaya,<br>
        41200 Klang, Selangor Darul Ehsan<br>
        Tel  : 03-33231001<span class="p">Fax  : 03-33232005<br>
        Email: <span class="p3">info@mypromosys.com</address>
    </div>



    <h2>Official Quotation</h2>
 
 
<dl class="floatleft">
   <dt style="font-size:80%;">To<space style="padding-left:49px;">:</space>111</dd>
   <dt style="font-size:80%;">Attn<space style="padding-left:41px;">:</space>22222</dd>
   <dt style="font-size:80%;">From<space style="padding-left:36px;">:</space>33333333</dd>
   <dt style="font-size:80%;">C.c<space style="padding-left:46px;">:</space>5555555</dd>
</dl>

   
<dl class="floatright">
   <dt style="font-size:80%;">Ref No<space>:</space>111</dt>
   <dt style="font-size:80%;">Date<space style="padding-left:49px;">:</space>22222</dd>
   <dt style="font-size:80%;">Page<space style="padding-left:49px;">:</space>33333333</dd>
</dl>


<!-- This is the line header Starting-->                    
<!--<div class:"lineheadeer"; id:"lineheadeer" style="height:100px" line-height: "0px;" padding-top:"30%;">-->
    <p class="lineheader1">Dear Sir/Madam<br>
    <styleline> Refer to our conversation and meeting, we are pleased to offer you with the following quotation. </styleline>

<table class="table table-bordered"; style="margin-top:100px;">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:3%;  border-style: solid black; text-align: left;">No</th>
    <th style="width:7%;  border-style: solid black; text-align: left;">Description</th>
    <th style="width:3%;  border-style: solid black; text-align: left;">Qty</th>
    <th style="width:3%;  border-style: solid black; text-align: left;">UOM</th>
    <th style="width:3%;  border-style: solid black; text-align: left;">Unit Price</th>
    <th style="width:5%;  border-style: solid black; text-align: left;">Sub-Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$100</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Lois</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Swanson</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$300</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Lois</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td style="padding-left:1%;">Brown</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">$250</td>
    <td style="text-align:center">Griffin</td>
    <td style="text-align:right; padding-right:1%;">$150</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">$150</td>
  </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td colspan="5" style="border-bottom:none; border-left-color:white; border-top:1px solid black; text-align:right;">Total : MYR</td>
      <td style="border-top:solid black; border-left:solid black; border-right:solid black; text-align:right; border-bottom:solid black;">653.64</td>
  </tr> 
 </table>
</div>



<div class="mypg">

<div>
<dl class="floatleft2;">
   <dt style="font-size:80%; padding-top:90%; padding-left:2px;">Term<space style="padding-left:7.55%;">:</space>30 Days</dd>
   <dt style="font-size:80%; padding-left:2px;" >Validity<space style="padding-left:7.70%;">:</space>30 Days from the above date</dd>
   <dt style="font-size:80%; padding-left:2px;">Delivery<space style="padding-left:7.45%;">:</space>2-3 weeks (Workings Days only.)</dd>
</dl>
</div>

<div>
<p style="font-size:80%; line-height:0.50%; height:1%; padding-left:8%; padding-top:2%"> We trust the above is in order and look forward to your favorable reply.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p style="font-size:80%; line-height:1px; padding-bottom:2px; padding-left:8%;">Please do not hesitate to contact us should you require any further information.</p>
</div>

<div>
<p style="font-size:80%; line-height:0.50%; height:1%; padding-left:8%; padding-top:2%">Yours faithfully,.<space2>I/We confirm acceptance of the above</space2></p>
</div>

<div>
<p style="font-size:80%; line-height:5%; height:1%; padding-left:8%; padding-top:4%">for Promosys Technology (M) Sdn. Bhd.</p>
</div>

<div>
<hr width=10%  align=left><br></hr><mdname>mdname<spacedate>Date</spacedate><spacesign>Sign/Chop</mdname>

<!--<mdname>mdname</mdname>-->

<hr2 width=10%  align=right></hr2> <!--<date>date</date>-->
</div>

<!--<p style="font-size:80%; line-height:5%; height:1%; padding-top:4%">date</p>-->


<!--<p class:"date" style="font-size:80%; padding-top:5%; height:1%; padding-left:63.50%;">date<spacemdname>mdname-->

<!--
 <dl class="floatright2;">
   <dt class="floatright2" style="font-size:80%; padding-left:8%;">I/We confirm acceptance of the above</space>
   <hr class="floatright2">
</dl> -->



<p  class="tfoot">Please refer to <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">
  http://mypromosys.com/terms/htm</a> for our standard terms and conditions.</p>
</p>

<p class="ufoot">*Document generated by CMS System</p>

   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is your code that you have tried?

Comment: forget the other errors,  concern that only be mention..

Comment: i think for the mean time i just creating the the properties for second table same as first table/layout that it needed. It solved my problems.

Answer (score 0):

i think for the mean time i just creating the the properties for second table same as first table/layout that it needed. It solved my problems.